# In VS (2010), where can I move the configuration dropdowns so they are still reachable but don't eat up vertical code space?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

As essentially everybody now, I have a widescreen monitor, which I dislike, but notebooks are all like that. I have little vertical space (768px) and I find it too little for proper coding. I'm trying to squeeze every last pixel from VS' GUI options. So far I have removed the status bar, the menu (shown by pressing alt, there is a plugin for that), the horizontal scrollbar, and some other stuff I can't remember because I don't miss them.

Some useless things are left, like the tabs bar, VS' title bar, and the "standard buttons" bar.

Well, I surely can't remove the app's title bar, and I found that I missed the tabs bar. And I need the standard buttons bar for one thing: change from debug to release and 32b to 64b and vice versa.

But those two items are pretty small, and the bar still eats up 20-so precious pixels, probably one and a half line of code. I'm probably being nazi here, but that bar consuming my coding space annoys me.

**How can I put those dropdowns somewhere else where they are at mouse reach ?**

I have tried to put the bar on the right side of the app, but the dropdowns disappear.

I don't mind having to click somewhere or hit a key for them to appear, as long as they disappear by themselves. Actually the bar can already be hidden and shown, but that takes an alt-key to make the menu appear, a right click to get the popup menu, a click on the "standard" item, modifying the dropdown contents, then another right click and another click to hide it back. That's too much.

Thank you for your time for I've been overly verbose as you can see and some more blah blah blah... (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in your context menu.

1. select `Add or Remove buttons` on a toolbar
2. choose `Customize`
3. on the `Commands` tab select radio button `Context menu`
4. in the drop down list, choose: `Editor Context Menus | Code Window`
5. press `Add Command` button
6. choose category `Build` and choose command `Solution Configurations` and press ok.
7. Do the same for `Solution Platforms`
8. press `Close` button

Bob's your uncle. Now they are in your context menu.

Comment: You can also add your own menu instead of adding a command, and then select that in the context menu drop down list, where the name will be `Editor Context Menus | Code Window | Whatever you named it`

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to commit to memory the **keyboard shortcut for the Configuration Manager**.

```
Alt + B, O
```

This will brink up the config manager window and have the current configuration hilighted so you can up/down arrow and select the one you want.  Then, just hit Enter and you're ready to go!

Also, if you're only using one monitor on a laptop, consider flipping into **Fullscreen mode**.

```
Shift + Alt + Enter
```

(For mouse, the only alternatives are on the task bar, which beyond just moving it to another place will still take up space).

Comment: Very helpful, thx ! (+1) Turns out the title bar CAN be removed !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to squeeze every last pixel, then you want Alt+Shift+Enter or via, a mouse: View>Fullscreen.

- It removes the title bar
- You get to keep the tabs
- You **don't** get to keep the standard buttons, however

Answer (score 1):

The [Productivity Power Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=189202) extension for Visual Studio 2010 will, among many other nifty things, allow you to put the tab bar along any window edge.

Comment: Nice link (+1). I tried it some time ago but I didn't like the tabs on the side /:

Answer (score 0):

bind those changes (32-64 and debug-release) to a key combination so you can dispence of yhe bar altogether

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use Fullscreen Mode in your case. SHIFT+ALT+ENTER